# How to extract part of Leaflet map as png image?

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

Wondering if it is possible to let user select part of Leaflet map and extract that portion of the map as png image. I have found plugins that can narrow things down to the selected area bounds, but I don't know if there's an API in leaflet that can get to the content out given the bounds.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the coords, and are using Mapbox to host your maps, then I would take a look at the Mapbox Static Maps API https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/ which you can easily use to have mapbox create a raster image for you.

Comment: not using Mapbox atm, thought that seems like what we need for this. I am thinking if I can render part of a leaftlet map as canvas and output a png from that.